# zoom the image while resize using range control and save the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image

I am uploading an image. when I use the range slider to preview the resize image that image size should not change rather it should zoom the image.

how to achieve this, can anyone suggest the way to do this.

```
    <input id="fileMobile" type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ng-click="thumbnailshow()" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
                                                                                    ngf-max-size="3MB" />

                                                                                <i ng-show=" Form.file.$error.pattern" style="color: red;"> File format allows only JPG, JPEG, PNG </i>
                                                                                <i ng-show=" Form.file.$error.maxSize" style="color: red;">File too large max-size:4MB </i>
                                                                                </br>
                                                                                <img width="275" height="95" ng-show="!!file" ngf-thumbnail="file" id="imageId"
                                                                                 />
    <div class="col-md-9">                                                                               
<label>Resize Image</label>                                                                             
 <input type="range" id="rangeId" min=0 max="100">                                                                         
  </div>
```

controller.js

```
var ranger = document.getElementById('rangeId'),
              image = document.getElementById('imageId');     
              width = image.width,
             height = image.height;

        ranger.onchange = function () 
        {
```

image.width = width * (ranger.value / 100);
image.height = height * (ranger.value / 100);
            }  //  it is enlarging the image but while using range slider change. when I upload an image it is uploading original image.

> when I change the range slider I need to zoom image and the zoomed portion of an image part only should take while file upload.

```
  var imageformat = '';
        var vm = this;
        $scope.uploadFile = function (file) { //function to call on form submit
              LogoUploads(file);

        }


        var LogoUploads = function (file) {
              if (file != undefined) {
                    Upload.upload({
                          url: '/LogoUploads', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
                          data: { file: file } //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
                    }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
                          console.log(resp);
                          $scope.FileName = resp.config.data.file.name;
                          imageformat = resp.config.data.file.type.split('/');
                          if (imageformat[1] == "jpeg") {
                                imageformat[1] = "jpg";
                          }
                          if (imageformat[1] == "png") {
                                imageformat[1] = "png";
                          }

                          ImageName = resp.data;
                          $scope.imagename = ImageName;

                          if ($scope.FileName != "" && $scope.FileName != undefined) {
                                UpdateInfo();

                          }
```

can I apply this css to me input type "range" will it zoom the image

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code here whatever you have tried

Comment: here, I shared  sample code.